# Cant get array to work from query

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I need the result from a query to become an array and use that array to pull data from the database on a second php mysqli query.

```
<?php
include"connection.php";
$pos = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM equipos");
$logos = array();
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos)){
$logos[] = "<br>'".$row['abrv']."'=>"."'".$row['logo']."'";
}
$logos = implode(",", $logos);

$enjuego = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE dprt='ftbls'");
while($part=mysqli_fetch_array($enjuego)){
$liga=$part['serie'];
$eq1= $part['eq1'];
$eq1s= strtoupper($eq1);
$eq2= $part['eq2'];
$eq2s= strtoupper($eq2);

echo $logos[$eq1].'<br>';
}
?>
```

It gives me the same error over and over again. This is the closest I came but just doesn’t work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

The error I get is: Warning: Illegal string offset 'gua' in line 18

Comment: You posted 20 lines of code and told us there's an error on line 22.

Comment: is `echo $logos[$eq1].'<br>';` your line 22

Comment: its line 18, sorry about the typo

Answer (score 1):

Here you convert your `$logos` array variable to a string type:

```
$logos = implode(",", $logos);
```

and then later at the end you want to access it again as if it were an array:

```
echo $logos[$eq1].'<br>';
```

that is the error you are getting.

Comment: You see, I’m trying to pull a result from the second query using a common element but addressing an image name in the first array. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

you have a number ordered array for $logos. you cant implode it just by implode(",", $logos), this way you are trying to implode a comma seperated array, (it should look like $logos=array("foo","bar"); to implode as comma seperated array.

$logo[] => this should look like; $logo=array("0"=>"foo", "1"=>"bar")
try dumping your array, you will see what is wrong (var_dump($logo);) after first while loop.

Comment: I whant the result from the first query to be like this:<br />
<br />
$logos = array(
'ame'=>'america',
'atn'=>'atlante',
'atl'=>'atlas',
'jag'=>'chiapas',
'caz'=>'cruzazul',
'gua'=>'guadalajara',
'leo'=>'leon',
'mty'=>'monterrey',
'mor'=>'morelia',
'pac'=>'pachuca',
'pue'=>'puebla',
'qto'=>'queretaro',
'sl'=>'sanluis',
'san'=>'santos',
'xol'=>'tijuana',
'tol'=>'toluca',
'tig'=>'uanl',
'pum'=>'unam',
);



This way I can use it on the second query to pull an image based on the name that the first query throws on the array

Answer (score 0):

First of, remove the implode as that will convert your array to a string.

Then you are trying to get the key "eq1" from table "partidos" in the $logos array, which might not exist (because the array will like this array( 0 => 'first', 1 => 'second', 2 => 'third' ) ).

You must have something that is common between "equipos" and "partidos", lets say "abrv" is the same thing as eq1 the solution would be:

```
<?php

include"connection.php";

$pos = mysqli_query($not, "SELECT * FROM equipos");

$logos = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos)){
    $logos[$row['abrv']] = "<br>'".$row['abrv']."'=>"."'".$row['logo']."'";
}

$enjuego = mysqli_query($not, "SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE dprt='ftbls'");

while($part = mysqli_fetch_array($enjuego)){
    $liga = $part['serie'];
    $eq1 = $part['eq1'];
    $eq1s = strtoupper($eq1);
    $eq2 = $part['eq2'];
    $eq2s = strtoupper($eq2);

    echo $logos[$eq1].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: The $eq1 is in fact the same as abrv they hold the same relation(equipos)
___________________________
|  logos       |   abrv   |
___________________________
| frstlogo.jpg  |  frst   |
___________________________
| scndlogo.jpg  | scnd    |
__________________________

(tournaments) 
___________________________
|     eq1       |  eq2     |
___________________________
|     frst      |  scnd    |
___________________________
| scndlogo.jpg  | scnd     |
___________________________



$logos[$eq1]